# Coinfiguring Embedded ApacheDS server with Spring Java Config

Tags: java, spring, apacheds

So I have an existing config file that configures an `org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource`.

```
@Configuration
public class LdapContextConfig {

    @Inject
    private LdapProperties ldapProperties;

    @Bean
    public ContextSource contextSource() {
        final TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy transactionAwareContextSourceProxy =
                new TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy(poolingContextSource());
        return transactionAwareContextSourceProxy;
    }

    @Bean
    public PoolingContextSource poolingContextSource() {
        final PoolingContextSource poolingContextSource = new MutablePoolingContextSource();
        poolingContextSource.setContextSource(ldapContextSource());
        poolingContextSource.setDirContextValidator(new DefaultDirContextValidator());
        poolingContextSource.setTestOnBorrow(true); //default false
        return poolingContextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() {
        final LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getUrl());
        ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getBase());
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getUserDn());
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getPassword());
        return ldapContextSource;
    }

}
```

This uses a custom `LdapProperties` class to pull the url, base, userDn, and password from a properties file when the application is deployed.

Now, I am trying to set up an embedded ApacheDS server to use in integration testing.

I have another config file to set up a an ApacheDS `DirectoryService`.

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedLdapConfig {

    @Bean
    public DirectoryService getDirectoryService() throws Exception {
        final DirectoryService directoryService = new DefaultDirectoryService();

        //other config

        return directoryService;
    }
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to map the ApacheDS `DirectoryService` to the Spring `LdapContextSource`.

I have injected the `DirectoryService` into my `LdapContextConfig` and created a separate `@Bean` for the embedded `LdapContextSource`.

```
@Inject
private DirectoryService directoryService;

@Bean
public LdapContextSource embeddedLdapContextSource() {
    final LdapContextSource embeddedLdapContextSource = /*convert DirectoryService to LdapContextSource*/;
    return embeddedLdapContextSource;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow get an `LdapContextSource` from an ApacheDS `DirectoryService`? If so, how would I go about doing it?